# Android Notification SetSound(URI) Not work

Tags: android, notifications, uri

This is Success.

notificationBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/testfile"));

However, in the following way is Not Work.

notificationBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("file:///data/data/com.Company.test/files/testfile.wav"));

File outFile = new File("/data/data/com.Company.test/files/testfile.wav");

outFile.exists() == true

File exists.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in `raw` folder 
and give uri path

```
 Uri path =  Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.testfile);
```

Comment: How to use the "file: /// +?"

Comment: This problem may be because of notification can not access my application's internal folder.  http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/how-to-solve-pvmferrnotsupported-error-while-playing-sound-t17270.html